# Triggers for checking complex uniqueness for table with soft deletes

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2017

I have a table that contains information about permits for various regions.

It has unique identity primary key, and a two column unique key which is the application's permit number and the region ID.

It also supports soft deletes; when a row is deleted it just sets a bit field.

I'm struggling to enforce uniqueness with the DB.

Can't use a UNIQUE constraint as it fails if a deleted item uses the permit number.
Can't see a way to use a check constraint because I need to run a query to check for duplicates.

I have got this far with a trigger:

```
        create table Test (
            ID int identity primary key,
            PN nvarchar(25),
            RID int,
            Deleted bit default(0)
        )
        go
        create trigger T_PN on Test instead of insert 
        as
        begin
            declare @pn nvarchar(25), @rid int
            select @pn = PN, @rid = RID from inserted 

            if exists(select ID from Test where PN = @pn and RID = @rid and Deleted = 0)
                RAISERROR('PN in use', 11, 1);
            else
                insert into Test select * from inserted
        end
```

However this won't work because of the identity column; `An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Test' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

This project is an ongoing rapid development project; the table will change regularly so hardcoding the column names is not an option.

I don't know the ramifications of using `IDENTITY_INSERT` within a trigger and it feels hacky and dangerous?

I'm leaning towards an app-layer solution, but am I missing anything?

Comment: Your trigger *assumes* a `INSERT` only ever contains 1 row; that is completely untrue.

Comment: A very good point, but at the moment that is not the problem; that I can solve. The identity problem I cannot.

Comment: But it *is* a problem. You should never be writting triggers like that.

Comment: Also `RAISERROR` in a trigger is a bad idea, it might not roll back properly, and it's not batch aborting. And why use an `instead of` trigger, an `after` trigger is at least a little more efficient.

Comment: @ThomA I am very appreciative of your final answer, but come on, this is a very unfinished unworking piece of experimental (and simplified test case) code I am asking for comments on to point me towards a solution, is it really that surprising it's got issues? Sometimes I think SO users expect people to post code that is production  ready except for the one highly specific problem they're asking about.

Comment: I think you're missing the point; it doesn't matter if it's test code or not, @Whelkaholism , a trigger should never be written assuming an `INSERT` only affects one row. The only time I would consider it acceptable is when showing someone else *why* it's a bad idea. The fact you've used the syntax suggests you aren't aware of the dangers, and why I've made you aware so that you *don't* make that mistake in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a filtered unique index instead (`UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`s don't support a `WHERE` clause in their definition):

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test (
   TestID int IDENTITY 
      CONSTRAINT PK_test PRIMARY KEY, --ALWAYS name your constraints
   PN nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
   RID int NOT NULL,
   Deleted bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Test_Deleted DEFAULT(0)
); ---ALWAYS name your constraints

GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Test_PN_RID_Active
   ON dbo.Test (PN,RID)
   WHERE Deleted = 0;
```

Then you can't `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) a row to be the same as an existing "undeleted" row:

```sql
--All work
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (PN,RID)
VALUES(N'abc',2),
      (N'abc',3),
      (N'def',3),
      (N'xyz',99);
GO
--Fails
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (PN,RID)
VALUES(N'abc',2);
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test;
GO

UPDATE dbo.Test
SET Deleted = 1
WHERE TestID = 1;
GO
--Now succeeds
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (PN,RID)
VALUES(N'abc',2);
GO
--Fails, it's the same as the row we just inserted
UPDATE dbo.Test
SET RID = 2
WHERE TestID = 2;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test;
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
```